# Visual Studio dragging the form

Tags: c#, forms, drag

Could someone explain to me how this code work

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void mainForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { //When a mouseButton is pressed down on the form
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
        { // if it is mouseButton1
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
```

I know it gives my form the possibility of being dragged around, but i don't understand how.

Thanks!

Comment: It treats the mouse button down as if it had been on the title bar (`HT_CAPTION`). The window manager then does the rest. You can just look up the constants and API functions involved, it's not that complicated.

Comment: Your DLL import allows additional logic to be imported, see the documentation for [ReleaseCapture()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SendMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It is half of what normally happens when you click the title bar of a window.   WM_NCHITTEST is the missing part, it is what normally produces HTCAPTION.   Using the Spy++ utility is a good way to see what messages a window gets, Petzold and MSDN is a good way to read about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comments were of great help :D